# Gitkraken on Windows behind a proxy doesn't work

Tags: windows, ssh, proxy, bitbucket, gitkraken

I installed Gitkraken and I'm trying to clone a repository from Bitbucket but it doesn't work, I get this error during the cloning process:

```
Failed to start ssh sesssion. Bad socket provided
```

I generated an authentification key on Gitkraken and accepted it with Bitbucket, so that's not the problem. I think it's because I'm behind a proxy, but I couldn't find any way to make it work. I'm using Windows 10.

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem. Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: No sadly, I gave up and I'm working on linux instead because proxy is easier to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, too. It could not connect using SSH while behind a proxy, but I ended up getting it working if I connected using HTTPS. This might be a useful workaround for you.